# Optaplanner select only entities in conflict

Tags: optaplanner

In the change and swap move selector, I would like to only consider moves that involve entities in conflict as they are more likely to improve the heuristic score.

How should this be done? What classes and interfaces do I have to reuse/extend? I looked at ScoreDirector and PhaseLifecycleListener.

Answer (score 0):

A MoveFilter might do that (if it's not in phase or solver cached as it changes ever step). See the course scheduling example and docs for how to use a filter.

I wouldn't recommend it though, as you still want to move non-conflicting entities at times. You might just want to focus more on those conflicting lectures. So I would keep a vanilla move selector in the mix.

The move filter isn't perfect either - the Guided Local Search feature (not yet available) is a better way to deal with this.

However, given the other question about the model and similar cases I 've seen, I 'd say moves are not your problem. A better model will make all these kinds of move tweaking obsolete.